# App engine downloading PHP code instead of displaying

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm using PHP55 to run a web-page on standard environment through Google App Engine. When I click the submit button on a form, it downloads the respective PHP code that should instead be executing. Here's my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /signUp.html
  static_files: www/signUp.html
  upload: www/signUp.html

- url: /submitEmail.php
  static_files: www/submitEmail.php
  upload: www/submitEmail.php

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

**EDIT 1**
So I initially tried the following for the handlers:

```
handlers:
-url: /(.+\.php)$
script: www/\1

-url: /
script: www/index.html

-url: /(.*)
script: www/\1
```

However this was in short - a disaster. Images and CSS didn't load after refreshing. **All I want is for `submitEmail.php` to execute when the user clicks submit on the form in `index.html`**.

To clarify this is my high-level structure:

```
www/
-index.html
-submitEmail.php
app.yaml
```

**EDIT 2**
Present state of `app.yaml` but when I submit the form I receive a 404 error.

```
handlers:
-url: /(.+\.php)$
script: www/\1

-url: /submitEmail.php
```

script: www/submitEmail.php

```
-url: /
script: www/index.html

-url: /(.*)
script: www/\1
```

Comment: Is the file extension of your PHP file `.html` or `.php`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include respective handler. Edited code snippet -> 'submitEmail.php'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the PHP code is delivered because you declared it as `static_files`. Static files are delivered as-is to the client when requested.

Change your handler like this:

```
- url: /submitEmail.php
  script: www/submitEmail.php
  upload: www/submitEmail.php
```

See also [app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref).

Comment: Then I get "An error occurred while parsing file: app.yaml. Unexpected attribute "upload" for mapping type script."

Comment: Ah yes. You'll need to drop that.

Comment: The problem you describe in the edited question seems like it has nothing to do with the original question. I suggest creating a new one and showing the contents of the HTML / PHP files because it is likely relevant.

Comment: Wait, forget my previous comment – you did use `script` for non-PHP resources, which is likely the problem.